# send persian string(utf-8) with VolleyMultipartRequest

Tags: android, utf-8, android-volley

how can send utf-8 string to server and save it . when send this string for example when send (لل) in database save (DD) please help me ?

```
@Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    params.put("body", edt_body.getText().toString());
    params.put("en_body", edt_en_body.getText().toString());
    params.put("title", edt_title.getText().toString());
    params.put("en_title", edt_en_title.getText().toString());
    params.put("mobile_id", DatabaseOpenHelper.mobile_id);
    params.put("key", DatabaseOpenHelper.key);
    return params;
  }
```

Comment: what db are you using? make sure its configured to acept utf-8

Comment: no problem in db when i use the postman to send data no problem

Comment: in your application, make sure are sending the right data (this a very common mistake while coding :) ).

Comment: no i debug my code all thing right i think set charset utf-8 before send data but how can do it?

Answer (score 2):

ok replace some code in class with

```
private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
    dataOutputStream.write(parameterName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.write(parameterValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}
```

and now right work